# Only see ' rows=System.Object[] ' when enumerating JSON results in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am returning a web service call that supposedly comes back in json format, and it does indeed appear to be valid json. As a string, it looks like this:

{"total":10,"rows":[{"process":"VISIO.EXE","computer_id":57,"last_used":"2016-04-20T01:34:09Z"},{"process":"VISIO.EXE","computer_id":64,"last_used":"2016-04-01T04:09:35Z"},{"process":"VISIO.EXE","computer_id":181,"last_used":"2016-03-10T23:02:53Z"},{"process":"VISIO.EXE","computer_id":230,"last_used":"2016-04-19T05:31:32Z"},{"process":"VISIO.EXE","computer_id":237,"last_used":"2016-04-04T10:23:23Z"},{"process":"VISIO.EXE","computer_id":284,"last_used":"2016-04-15T10:54:29Z"},{"process":"VISIO.EXE","computer_id":8401,"last_used":"2016-05-12T21:55:39Z"},{"process":"VISIO.EXE","computer_id":9045,"last_used":"2016-05-12T08:10:40Z"},{"process":"VISIO.EXE","computer_id":9527,"last_used":"2016-05-11T00:49:11Z"},{"process":"VISIO.EXE","computer_id":10198,"last_used":"2016-05-06T06:59:29Z"}]}

I am trying to enumerate through the results, using the following script. I have tried all of the listed options 1-4 by uncommenting them out one at a time, but I cannot get more than one result to return.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
$url = 'https://servername:port/api/sam/raw_app_usage_property_values?criteria={"and":[["process","=","visio.exe"]]}&limit=100&columns[]=process&columns[]=computer_id&columns[]=last_used'
# option 1. get all results, we see a full list of processes, full string returned
#$results = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $headers
#write-host $results
# option 2. get all results but break them down as part of the request. Only one result returned - @{total=10; rows=System.Object[]}
#$results = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $headers | ConvertFrom-Json
#write-host $results
# option 3. use a different method, which supposedly breaks down the request natively. Only one result returned - @{total=10; rows=System.Object[]}
#$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $headers
#write-host $results
# option 4. get content directly from file, only one result returned - @{total=10; rows=System.Object[]}
#$results = (Get-Content -path "C:\temp\raw_app_usage_property_values.json" -raw)
# is there anything in the array?
foreach ($result in $results) {
    write-host $result
}
```

Comment: You will need to use either `ConvertFrom-JSON` if you have a string (from `Invoke-WebRequest` or `Get-Content`), or use `Invoke-RestMethod` which implicitly converts from JSON, before you can do what @mark-bertenshaw suggests.

Comment: what exactly is the value of your `$results` and `$results.rows`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting the data back. Remember that the returned object has two properties, "total" and "rows".

Try:

```
foreach ($result in $results.rows) {
    write-host $result
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're spot on. :)